# How to avoid multiple "to" in sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

In sometimes I use the multiple "to" in a single sentence. But I try to avoid this kind of sentence formation.

> After eight years I again went **to** Chennai **to** join my first Job

Any simple solution for this kind of sentence formation?

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical or even stylistically undesirable about using *to* twice in a sentence.

Comment: oh I thought It was a mistake. thanks for the info @ThePhoton

Comment: Another preposition that may seem overused is *for*; e.g., "He went for a test for pulmonary function." It's grammatical and colloquial English.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @DrMoishePippik

Comment: Maybe you could use: "... I again went to Chennai and joined my first job". it's almost like: "I go and see something", which is preferable to "I go to see something".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for your sentence.

English follows a "head-body" pattern very often.

There's lots of situations where, if elements share the same "head", it only has to be specified once.  Articles and prepositions are common "heads".

> I took the black socks and blue socks from the shelf = I took the black socks and the blue socks from the shelf.

> I wanted to see and talk to her = I wanted to see and to talk to her.

> I went to the store and the park = I went to the store and to the park.

However. "to" as a spatial preposition in the targeting/destination/intent sense, and "to" as an infinitive marker, are completely different "heads" and can't be combined like that.

You can do this, though:

> After eight years I again went to join my first Job at Chennai.